# Upright maths in display mode, but italics in align environment in beamer class

Tags: beamer, math-mode, align

I use `mathastext` like this

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
```

This gives me upright math throughout my document in an article class document, but in a beamer class document I end up with upright math in display math mode `\[ ... \]`, but in the align environment `\begin{align} ... \end{align}` the math is italic.

How do I get upright math in an align environment as well?

---

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

Math in display
\[
abc
\]

Text...

Math in align
\begin{align}
abc
\end{align}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `beamer` class overwrites the work of `mathastext`: it assigns letters and digits to some other fonts, after `mathastext`. I will investigate. But the simplest would be to get upright math from beamer itself, and forget about `mathastext`.

Comment: @jfbu Thank you for your input. I'm using `mathastext` to use Biolinum as sans-serif (and math) font and Linux Libertine as serif font. I don't know how to achieve this without `mathastext`.

Comment: To use `mathastext` with `beamer` one needs either to use `professionalfont` as class option, or to use `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`. Notice the two distinct spellings. See my answer. I have posted an issue on the beamer development site to ask for `mathastext` in future releases of `beamer` to be among the packages for which `beamer` automatically activates its class option `professionalfont`.

Comment: Some of the advanced functionalities of `mathastext` (via the use of math active characters) are annihilated by `beamer` in certain environments such as `align`, `gather` etc.. as an indirect result of a certain "`Math mode color hackery`". This explains why you observed that things went awry in `align` although they looked ok in standard display math (letters were math active and thus used the mathastext definitions). I have posted a proposal on the `beamer` site for an alternative `math mode hackery` which would not amputate `mathastext` of some of its functionalities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rewrite of my first answer. There are two options:

1. Use the `professionalfont` beamer class option and `mathastext` exactly as in your code, but notice the spelling without a final `s`. Alternatively, and as is recommended by a warning in the log file, issue rather in the preamble `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` (*with a final s!*).
2. Do not use the `professionalfont` class option nor `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`, do not load package `mathastext`, and exploit the fact that then the `beamer` class by itself already reassigns letters and digits to the document sans text font. There is perhaps an option somewhere in beamer to tell it to get the letters upright. But, not knowing it I provide a hack which has the desired effect.

The difference between the two options is in the treatment of characters such as `=`, `?` and `;`. In option 1, they will be from Biolinum (this is done by `mathastext` package), in option 2 they will be from the default math (usually Computer Modern) fonts.

### Option 1 (professionalfont+mathastext)

> [image: beamer upright I]

Code for option 1:

```
%\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}
%  or better (according to a warning in log file if the above):
\documentclass {beamer}
\usefonttheme {professionalfonts}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[defaultmathsizes]{mathastext}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  This is serif text, $sans math:E=mc^2$ (we see it is upright and sans), and
  then display math which is also upright and sans:
  \[
  E=mc^2=abc;XYZ=tuv=TUV<123?
  \]

  Some serif text and then display math (with align)
  \begin{align} 
   E=mc^2=abc;XYZ=tuv=TUV<123?
  \end{align}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Option 2: hack, but no mathastext

> [image: beamer upright 2]

Code for option 2:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usefonttheme[stillsansserifmath]{serif}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\begingroup
   \count0 \sympureletters
   \count2 \symnumbers
  \@tfor\x:=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do
  {\global\expandafter\mathcode\expandafter`\x=\numexpr\expandafter\mathcode\expandafter`\x-\count0*256+\count2*256\relax}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

  This is serif text, $sans math:E=mc^2$ (we see it is upright and sans), and
  then display math which is also upright and sans:
  \[
  E=mc^2=abc;XYZ=tuv=TUV<123?
  \]

  Some serif text and then display math (with align)
  \begin{align} 
   E=mc^2=abc;XYZ=tuv=TUV<123?
  \end{align}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

As an aside, not directly related to the OP question, I have noticed differences between `pdflatex`, and 
`lualatex/xelatex` with the following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \showboxdepth\maxdimen
  \showboxbreadth\maxdimen
  \setbox0\hbox{$=$}\showbox0\box0
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The font is `cmss` with `pdflatex` but `cmr` with `lualatex/xetex`.

```
pdftex:
> \box0=
\hbox(4.05148+0.0)x8.5167
.\mathon
.\OT1/cmss/m/n/10.95 =
.\mathoff

lualatex:
> \box0=
\hbox(4.01727+0.0)x8.5167, direction TLT
.\mathon
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 =
.\mathoff

xetex:
> \box0=
\hbox(4.01727+0.0)x8.5167
.\mathon
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 =
.\mathoff
```

Comment: since `beamer v3.34`, no need for `professionalfonts` to use  `mathastext` in `beamer` class.